# Размер приложения под iPhone 6

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone

Друзья, есть приложение, свои вьюшки не рисовал, использую стандартные TableView. Подключаю Google Maps, которые отображается так же в вьюшке стандартной. На iPhone 6  все растягивается, как устранить?

Comment: Constraints?
Все вьюшки стандартные(UIView). Что значит _растягивается_ ?

Comment: @tragvar, это значит, что в размерах больше, на презентации об этом говорили.

Comment: Может, скриншот что ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавить иконки и лаунчскрины под новые разрешения экранов.